# Force copy files off CRC error filled hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista, crc

So I have a dying Western Digital hard drive and I have a new Western Digital hard drive that I want to transfer all the data to. I have the new HDD hooked up by a SATA to USB adapter. I want to transfer all the pictures, etc to the new HDD. I was unable to because of the CRC errors. I have ran chkdsk /f /r and it didn't work because the drive is just simply dying.

**What tool will let me bypass CRC and continue on with the copying?**

***OS:*** Vista Home Prem. 32bit

Comment: Replace the drive.

Comment: @TheLakersHighlights: since this question could be read by others later, consider accepting the answer that best describes what to do.  or, if you can figure out what happened and how to duplicate it, add your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) at level 5 on the drive in question, then you should have success salvaging whatever is still readable.

Comment: How do u know this will work?

Comment: @The: I've been a computing expert for 15+ years now and have used SpinRite many times and understand how it operates and why it works. It disables the drive's internal ECC and applies its own algorithms to attempt to extract data from damaged sectors. SpinRite has been around for well over ten years.

Comment: I've never used SpinRite before but it looks like a valuable addition to any data recovery toolset. The latest version was released in 2004, do you know if it has any troubles with the latest version of NTFS included in Windows 7?

Comment: @tas: SpinRite *FINALLY* became filesystem-agnostic as of version 6. Yay! ext4, HFS+, UFS, ZFS, whatever, it'll work. Gibson is a graybeard; he's old-school and he knows his stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Your hard drive is not full of CRC errors, it is full of bad sectors. I would stop using your computer and run GetDataBack or R-STUDIO Network Edition over the hard drive and copy as much as you can to another drive.

Comment: R-STUDIO is decent; I've used it, but it's more tuned to filesystem corruption than a failing disk (IMHO). If the drive is failing (and in this case it clearly is) I'd give SpinRite a shot at it first, followed by R-STUDIO to recover as much data as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try booting into a live linux CD, or linux usb and mount the two drives and transfer that way.  Worth a shot.

Comment: I was already booted into UBCD for Win and it gave the same error.