# File copy software that first checks for errors and than copies only undamaged files?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, robocopy, crc

I'm trying to copy files from a damaged HDD to a fine one (both connected via USB 3.0 under Windows 8.1) but I'm having a hard time since it's more than 1TB of data. I'm using robocopy with r:0 and w:0 but when a file with CRC error is found the copy process gets stuck for at least one minute for every damaged file, the dead time is not proportional to the file size and having more than 10k damaged files you can imagine how long it's taking.

I've tried other softwares but it's always the same, no matter if I say to skip a file with errors or set the wait time to 0 the copy process always waits a random amount of time before going to the next file so I was wondering... is there a software that can check for errors BEFORE trying to copy and than copies only the files without errors?

I also use Ubuntu so if there are linux utilities that work similar to robocopy or that answer my question please let me know!

Thanks everyone ;)

Comment: What other tools have you tried?  (This one?  http://www.goodlucksoft.com/copy-bad-disk.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/417391/how-to-copy-files-with-an-option-for-skipping-stuck-files.

Comment: I already read the question you linked and tried all the sw listed but the problem still remains, instead of skipping right to another file when an error is found it waits and waits and waits... and after some time starts with the next file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force copy files off CRC error filled hard drive](http://superuser.com/questions/119647/force-copy-files-off-crc-error-filled-hard-drive)

Comment: already read, hdd already fixed as it was possible... but that's not the point! all i want to know is how can i check for crc error before copying and then copy only undamaged files

Comment: FYI:  The retry mechanism is part of the hard drive and is low-level so no windows based software can bypass it.  You would need probably need a program written in assembly to disable it.  Even then errors are part of a hard drives normal life, and many sectors are secretly repaired with ECC recovery data.  If you turn that off then even more files would be unusable.  Based on SMART data I have seen hard drive with 1,000,000+ ecc correct sectors.

Comment: ok, and that's fine... but I don't want to copy all data even if it have errors nor I want to disable the drive error correction! As I said I just want a copying SW that first checks all files in the drive to know which are corrupted (CRC error) and which are still integer and just then tries to copy the undamaged files... I can't believe the only way is manually checking every single file for errors and move the good ones one by one!

Anyway, if the latter is the only option: is there a CRC error checking software? (free is better)

Answer (score -1):

Roadkil's Unstoppable Copier

http://roadkil.net/listing.php/C1/Data%20Recovery !